# Is there any way to tell which questions a deleted user effected?

Tags: support, voting

Recently a user got deleted and I would like to see which questions that has effected. When I delete my account does this also happen to other users?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, and this is by design. Because it's possible that users may know which user had votes invalidated or an account removed, revealing which posts were voted on and how reveals their voting history, which is a big problem. As such, we can not show you this information.

Any time that a user deletes their account and has cast votes, those votes are generally removed upon deletion. For some users with large voting histories, we will review their account before deletion and sometimes retain those votes. This is handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Were my votes casted reversed on the accounts I renewed recently?